# Error upon core data change processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I am working on a coin collection app, and I have recently started integrating core data into my app. I have a core data database which stores custom CoinCategory objects and each CoinCategory object has an array of Coin objects. This way, my app stores everything in terms of categories.

When I integrated the core data, I can add my first category without any errors and delete it without any problems, but when I add in a second coin category, I experience the following error:

`2017-06-26 09:55:37.218 CoinCollection[18889:12839563] -[CoinCollection.CoinCategory compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000236cc0
2017-06-26 09:55:37.219215-0400 CoinCollection[18889:12839563] [error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[CoinCollection.CoinCategory compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000236cc0 with userInfo (null)
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[CoinCollection.CoinCategory compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000236cc0 with userInfo (null)`

Could anyone please advise me on how to fix this? Thank you very much!

I am attaching my code below for my viewcontroller and the app delegate that is running the core data.

```
    AppDelegate.swift
    //  We customize the app, system-wide
    import UIKit
    import CoreData


    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



var window: UIWindow?



//  MARK: - Core Data stack
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoinCollection")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription,
        error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
// MARK: - Core Data Saving support
func saveContext ()
{
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

    if context.hasChanges
    {
        do
        {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch
        {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. 
            //You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
    }
```

And then for my view controller. Notice that I get a Coin object from a sub-viewcontroller that invokes this method, and that we decide whether the Coin object fits into the existing categories. If not, then we add the new Coin.

```
    //  Controls the table view controller showing the general coins (one per each category)
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class CoinTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {


//this is an array of all the coins in the collection
//each row of this two-dimensional array represents a new category
var coinsByCategory: [CoinCategoryMO] = []
var fetchResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<CoinCategoryMO>!


//other attributes....





////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //we now fetch the data
    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<CoinCategoryMO> = CoinCategoryMO.fetchRequest()

    if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
    {
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "coinCategory", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        fetchResultController.delegate = self

        do
        {
            try fetchResultController.performFetch()
            if let fetchedObjects = fetchResultController.fetchedObjects
            {
                self.coinsByCategory = fetchedObjects
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    //configure even more....       
}



// MARK: - Table view data soure

func deleteCoinCategory(rowPath: IndexPath)
{
    if 0 <= rowPath.row && rowPath.row < self.coinsByCategory.count
    {
        //we have just tested that the rowPath index is valid
        if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
        {
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let coinCategoryToDelete = self.fetchResultController.object(at: rowPath)
            context.delete(coinCategoryToDelete)

            appDelegate.saveContext()
        }
    }
}

func deleteCoin(c: Coin, indexOfSelectedCategory: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    //we have a coin that we want to delete from this viewcontroller
    //and the data contained in it.
    //
    //the parameter indexOfSelectedCategory refers to the IndexPath of the
    //row in the TableView contained in THIS viewcontroller whose category
    //of coins we are modifying in this method
    //
    //Return value: a boolean that indicates whether a single coin has
    //been deleted - meaning that the user should return to the parentviewcontroller
    if 0 < indexOfSelectedCategory.row && indexOfSelectedCategory.row < self.coinsByCategory.count && self.coinsByCategory[indexOfSelectedCategory.row].coinCategory?.hasCoin(c: c) == true
    {
        //the index is valid as it refers to a category in the coinsByCategory array
        //and the examined category has the coin in question
        if self.coinsByCategory[indexOfSelectedCategory.row].coinCategory?.count == 1
        {
            //the coin "c" that we are going to delete is the only coin in the entire category
            self.deleteCoinCategory(rowPath: indexOfSelectedCategory)

            return true
        }
        else
        {
            //more than one coin in the category
            self.coinsByCategory[indexOfSelectedCategory.row].coinCategory?.removeCoin(c: c)

            //we save the changes in the database...
            if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
            {
                appDelegate.saveContext()
            }

            return false
        }
    }

    return false
}

func addCoin(coinToAdd: Coin)
{
    //we check over each category to see if the coin can be added
    for category in self.coinsByCategory
    {
        if category.coinCategory?.coinFitsCategory(aCoin: coinToAdd) == true
        {
            //we can add the coin to the category
            category.coinCategory?.addCoin(newCoin: coinToAdd)

            if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
            {
                //we save changes to the database
                appDelegate.saveContext()

                //we are DONE with this function
                return
            }
        }
    }

    //since the coinToAdd does not fall in the existing categories, we create a new one
    if let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)
    {
        let newCategory = CoinCategoryMO(context: appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext)


        newCategory.coinCategory = CoinCategory(coins: [coinToAdd], categoryType: CoinCategory.CategoryTypes.COUNTRY_VALUE_AND_CURRENCY)


        print("Saving data to context ...")
        appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
}



//delegate methods control the core data database
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
{
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?)
{
    switch type
    {
    case .insert :
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath
        {
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
        }

    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath
        {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }

    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath
        {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }

    default:
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    if let fetchedObjects = controller.fetchedObjects
    {
        self.coinsByCategory = fetchedObjects as! [CoinCategoryMO]
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>)
{
    tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

I am looking forward to hearing your thoughts and thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT:

My code for the CoinCategory class:

```
    //  This class is supposed to represent a category of coin objects in CoreData

import Foundation
import CoreData

    public class CoinCategory: NSObject, NSCoding
    {
        //These are the various types of categories that a user can create out of their coin collection
        enum CategoryTypes : NSString
        {
            case COUNTRY_VALUE_AND_CURRENCY = //...
            case COUNTRY = //...
            case YEAR = //...
            case CURRENCY = //...
            case NO_CATEGORY = //...
        }

//this struct is used to encode data in Key-Value pairs per the NSCoding protocol
struct Keys
{
    static let Current_Category_Type = "current_category_type"
    static let Coins_In_Category = "coins_in_category"
}

//this is the collection of the coins in the category
var coinsInCategory: [Coin] = []  //initially we have no coins in the collection
var currentCategoryType : CategoryTypes.RawValue = ""

public var count : NSNumber
{
    get
    {
        //..number of coins in category
    }
}

public var array : [Coin]
{
    get
    {
        //read-only copy of the Coins array..
    }
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    //we decode this object's information
    if let categoryTypeObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Current_Category_Type) as? CategoryTypes.RawValue
    {
        self.currentCategoryType = categoryTypeObject
    }

    if let coinsInCategoryArrayObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Coins_In_Category) as? [Coin]
    {
        self.coinsInCategory = coinsInCategoryArrayObject
    }
}

public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    //we encode this object's information
    aCoder.encode(currentCategoryType, forKey: Keys.Current_Category_Type)
    aCoder.encode(self.coinsInCategory, forKey: Keys.Coins_In_Category)
}

override init()
{
    super.init()
    self.currentCategoryType = CategoryTypes.COUNTRY_VALUE_AND_CURRENCY.rawValue
    self.coinsInCategory = []
}

convenience init(coins: [Coin], categoryType: CategoryTypes.RawValue)
{
    self.init()
    self.coinsInCategory = coins

    if isACategoryType(categoryType: categoryType) == true
    {
        self.currentCategoryType = categoryType
    }
    else
    {
       self.currentCategoryType = CategoryTypes.NO_CATEGORY.rawValue
    }
}

func isACategoryType(categoryType: NSString) -> Bool
{
    switch categoryType
    {
    case CategoryTypes.COUNTRY_VALUE_AND_CURRENCY.rawValue:
        return true
    case CategoryTypes.COUNTRY.rawValue:
        return true
    case CategoryTypes.YEAR.rawValue:
        return true
    case CategoryTypes.CURRENCY.rawValue:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func addCoin(newCoin: Coin)
{
    //we are adding a new Coin object to this category 
    //if it falls into the category's type
    if self.coinFitsCategory(aCoin: newCoin) == true
    {
        self.coinsInCategory.append(newCoin)
    }
}

func coinFitsCategory(aCoin: Coin) -> Bool
{
    //this function tests if aCoin fits into the category type
    //but that all varies depending on which category the coin is
    if self.coinsInCategory.count == 0
    {
        //this category is currently empty, so any addition goes!
        return true
    }

    //otherwise, this category is not empty... so we are now going to 
    //examine the situation more critically
    let testCoin = self.coinsInCategory[0]


    switch self.currentCategoryType
    {
        case CategoryTypes.COUNTRY_VALUE_AND_CURRENCY.rawValue:
            return (testCoin.getCountry().lowercased == aCoin.getCountry().lowercased) && (testCoin.getValue() == aCoin.getValue()) && (testCoin.getDenomination().lowercased == aCoin.getDenomination().lowercased)

    case CategoryTypes.COUNTRY.rawValue:
        return testCoin.getCountry().lowercased == aCoin.getCountry().lowercased

    case CategoryTypes.CURRENCY.rawValue:
        return testCoin.getDenomination().lowercased == aCoin.getDenomination().lowercased

    case CategoryTypes.YEAR.rawValue:
        return testCoin.getYear() == aCoin.getYear()

    default:
        return false
    }
}

func getIndexOfCoinInCollection(coin: Coin) -> Int
{
    //we are going to return -1 if the coin does not exist in the collection
    //and are going to return the index otherwise if yes
    for i in 0..<self.coinsInCategory.count
    {
        if coinsInCategory[i] == coin
        {
            return i
        }
    }

    //have not found anything
    return -1
}

func removeCoin(at: Int)
{
    //we remove the coin at the index if it is in a valid range of the coinInCategory array
    if isValidArrayIndex(index: at)
    {
        self.coinsInCategory.remove(at: at)
    }
}

func getCoin(at: Int) -> Coin?
{
    //we return nil if there is an issue in accessing the coin
    if isValidArrayIndex(index: at)
    {
        return self.coinsInCategory[at]
    }
    else
    {
        return nil
    }
}

func assignCoin(at: Int,c: Coin)
{
    if isValidArrayIndex(index: at)
    {
        self.coinsInCategory[at].assign(right: c)
    }
}

func deleteAllCoins()
{
    //we delete all the coin in this category
    self.coinsInCategory.removeAll()
}

func removeCoin(c: Coin)
{
    //we delete a coin from the category
    for i in 0..<self.coinsInCategory.count
    {
        if self.coinsInCategory[i] == c
        {
            //the coin at index "i" is equal to the coin "c" that we want to delete from the category
            self.coinsInCategory.remove(at: i)
            return
        }
    }
}

func hasCoin(c: Coin) -> Bool
{
    return getIndexOfCoinInCollection(coin: c) != -1
}

func swapValuesWithAnotherCategory(other: CoinCategory)
{
    swap(&self.currentCategoryType, &other.currentCategoryType)
    swap(&self.coinsInCategory,&other.coinsInCategory)
}

func swapCoins(indexOne: Int, indexTwo: Int)
{
    if isValidArrayIndex(index: indexOne) && isValidArrayIndex(index: indexTwo)
    {
        swap(&self.coinsInCategory[indexOne],&self.coinsInCategory[indexTwo])
    }
}

private func isValidArrayIndex(index: Int) -> Bool
{
    return (0 <= index && index < coinsInCategory.count)
}    
    }
```

And then the coin category class:
                //  This provides the class definition of Class Coin for the project

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    enum TimePeriods: String
    {
        //this enumeration represents the different time periods that a 
        //coin was minted in, for the sake of this programn
        case BCE = "BCE"
        case CE = "CE"
    }

    public class Coin : NSObject, NSCoding
    {
        //this struct represents all the keys used in encoding and decoding this object
        struct Keys
        {
            static let Country = "country"
            static let Mint = "mint"
            static let Year = "year"
            static let Currency = "currency"
            static let Value = "value"
            static let Grade = "grade"
            static let Comments = "comments"
            static let NumInstances = "numberInstances"
            static let Description = "description"
            static let Obverse = "obverse"
            static let Reverse = "reverse"
        }
//this represents a coin in the table view
static let GRADING_LOWER_LIMIT: NSNumber = 1
static let GRADING_UPPER_LIMIT: NSNumber = 70

//this represents the default strings returned if a field does not have the needed information
static let DEFAULT_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME: NSString = "(Description?)"
static let DEFAULT_COMMENTS: NSString = "(Comments?)"
static let DEFAULT_DENOMINATION: NSString = "(Denomination?)"
static let DEFAULT_MINT: NSString = "(Mint?)"
static let DEFAULT_COUNTRY: NSString = "(Country?)"
static let DEFAULT_YEAR: NSString = "(Year?)"
static let DEFAULT_GRADE: NSString = "(Grade?)"
static let DEFAULT_VALUE_AND_DENOMINATION: NSString = "(Value?) (Currency?)"

static let OBVERSE_IMAGE_STRING : NSString = "Obverse"
static let REVERSE_IMAGE_STRING : NSString = "Reverse"

static private let BULLET = "➣ "           //represents the kind of bullet to be used to build a complete summary of the coin

//declare members with setters and getters
private var country: NSString = ""        //what country/empire/etc. used in?
private var mint: NSString = ""            //where minted? EX: US Mint, St. Petersburg
private var year: NSNumber? = nil              //what year minted? per gregorian calendar
                                    //the year can be negative to represent the BCE period
                                    //positive to represent the CE periods
private var typeCurrency: NSString = ""     //what is the unit of value? EX: Cents, dollars, centavos, etc
private var theValue: NSNumber = 0         //how many? EX: how many dollars, cents, centavos, etc.?


//additional information about the coin
private var grade: NSNumber?            //on the american grading scale for coins. 1-70
private var comments: NSString = ""        //extra comments stored by the user for himself


private var numberOfInstances: NSNumber = 0 //number of coins exactly like this. EX: 1,2,3,4...etc? For each instance, it must be >= 1.

//This describes the type of the coin
//EX: Walking Liberty Quarter, Barber Quarter, Standing Liberty Quarter... etc
private var descriptiveName: NSString = ""

private var obverseImage: UIImage? = nil
private var reverseImage: UIImage? = nil


public var valueAndDenomination: NSString
{
    get
    {
        //need to check four cases
        //case 1: we have the right values for value and denomination
        //case 2: we do not have a value but do have denomination
        //case 3: we have a value but do not have denomination
        //case 4: we do not have both
        //
        //the reason why we consider 0 to be an empty value is because a coin that was worth 
        //nothing would not have been minted in the first place!!!
        if (self.theValue != 0 && self.typeCurrency != "")
        {
            //have value and denomination
            return "\(self.theValue) \(self.typeCurrency)" as NSString //like "20 Cents"
        }

        else if (self.theValue == 0 && self.typeCurrency != "" )
        {
            //do not have value, but have denomination
            return "(Value?) \(self.typeCurrency)" as NSString
        }

        else if (self.theValue != 0 && self.typeCurrency == "")
        {
            //we have value, but do not have denomination
            return "\(self.theValue) (Currency?)" as NSString
        }

        else
        {
            //we do not have both
            return Coin.DEFAULT_VALUE_AND_DENOMINATION as NSString
        }

    }
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    //we decode this object's information
    if let countryObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Country) as? NSString
    {
        self.country = countryObject
    }

    if let mintObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Country) as? NSString
    {
        self.mint = mintObject
    }

    if let yearObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Year) as? NSNumber
    {
        self.year = yearObject
    }

    if let currencyObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Currency) as? NSString
    {
        self.typeCurrency = currencyObject
    }

    if let valueObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Value) as? NSNumber
    {
        self.theValue = valueObject
    }

    if let gradeObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Grade) as? NSNumber
    {
        self.grade = gradeObject
    }

    if let commentObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Comments) as? NSString
    {
        self.comments = commentObject
    }

    if let numInstancesObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.NumInstances) as? NSNumber
    {
        self.numberOfInstances = numInstancesObject
    }

    if let descriptiveNameObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Description) as? NSString
    {
        self.descriptiveName = descriptiveNameObject
    }

    if let obverseImageObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Obverse) as? UIImage
    {
        self.obverseImage = obverseImageObject
    }

    if let reverseImageObject = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: Keys.Reverse) as? UIImage
    {
        self.reverseImage = reverseImageObject
    }
}
override init()
{
    //default initializer
    super.init()

    self.country = ""
    self.mint = ""
    self.year = nil
    self.typeCurrency = ""
    self.theValue = 0
    self.comments = ""
    self.numberOfInstances = 1
    self.descriptiveName = ""
    self.obverseImage = nil
    self.reverseImage = nil
}

init(country: NSString,year: Int?,typeCurrency: NSString, theValue: NSNumber,mint: NSString,grade: Int?,numInstances: NSNumber = 1,description: NSString, comments: NSString)
{
    super.init()
    self.country = country
    self.mint = mint
    self.year = year! as NSNumber
    self.typeCurrency = typeCurrency
    self.theValue = theValue
    self.comments = comments
    self.numberOfInstances = numInstances
    self.descriptiveName = description

    self.obverseImage = nil
    self.reverseImage = nil
}

init(country: NSString,year: NSNumber?,typeCurrency: NSString, theValue: NSNumber,mint: NSString,grade: NSNumber?,numInstances: NSNumber = 1,description: NSString, comments: NSString,obverseImage: UIImage, reverseImage: UIImage)
{
    super.init()
    self.country = country
    self.mint = mint
    self.year = year
    self.typeCurrency = typeCurrency
    self.theValue = theValue
    self.comments = comments
    self.numberOfInstances = numInstances
    self.descriptiveName = description
}

public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    //we encode the coin's information
    aCoder.encode(self.country, forKey: Keys.Country)
    aCoder.encode(self.mint, forKey: Keys.Mint)
    aCoder.encode(self.year, forKey: Keys.Year)
    aCoder.encode(self.typeCurrency, forKey: Keys.Currency)
    aCoder.encode(self.theValue, forKey: Keys.Value)
    aCoder.encode(self.grade, forKey: Keys.Grade)
    aCoder.encode(self.comments, forKey: Keys.Comments)
    aCoder.encode(self.numberOfInstances, forKey: Keys.NumInstances)
    aCoder.encode(self.descriptiveName, forKey: Keys.Description)
    aCoder.encode(self.obverseImage, forKey: Keys.Obverse)
    aCoder.encode(self.reverseImage, forKey: Keys.Reverse)
}



//setter and getter functions for class members...


func getCompleteSummary() -> NSString
{
    //returns a bulleted list that represents the coin 
    //and it describes every single detail...
}

func getIncompleteSummary() -> String
{
        //returns a bulleted list string that represents the coin
        //and it describes every single detail...     
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

func ofSameType(rhs: Coin) -> Bool
{
    return (self.getCountry().lowercased == rhs.getCountry().lowercased) && (self.getValue() == rhs.getValue()) && (self.getDenomination().lowercased == rhs.getDenomination().lowercased)
}

public static func==(lhs: Coin, rhs: Coin) -> Bool
{
    //we compare two coin objects for equality in ALL Categories
    return  lhs.country.lowercased == rhs.country.lowercased &&
            lhs.theValue == rhs.theValue &&
            lhs.typeCurrency.lowercased == rhs.typeCurrency.lowercased &&
            lhs.mint.lowercased == rhs.mint.lowercased &&
            lhs.year == rhs.year &&
            lhs.grade == rhs.grade &&
            lhs.comments == rhs.comments &&
            lhs.numberOfInstances == rhs.numberOfInstances &&
            lhs.descriptiveName == rhs.descriptiveName &&
            lhs.obverseImage == rhs.obverseImage &&
            lhs.reverseImage == rhs.reverseImage
}

func assign(right: Coin)
{
    //we implement this instead of overloading the assignment "=" operator
    //as it is not possible to overload the "=" operator
    //we assign the right-hand-coin's field values
    //to the left-hand coin's side
    self.country = right.country
    self.theValue = right.theValue
    self.typeCurrency = right.typeCurrency
    self.mint = right.mint
    self.year = right.year
    self.grade = right.grade
    self.comments = right.comments
    self.numberOfInstances = right.numberOfInstances
    self.descriptiveName = right.descriptiveName
    self.obverseImage = right.obverseImage
    self.reverseImage = right.reverseImage
}

    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if in my sample code there is a function that just has comments in it that I have removed my code and replaced it with comments to reduce the post's length to a certain length of characters that the forum would allow me to post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your `CoinCategory` class does not implement the `compare:` method:

> [CoinCollection.CoinCategory compare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000236cc0

My guess is that the FRC is trying to compare the `coinCategory` attribute of the second `CoinCategoryMO` to the `coinCategory` attribute of the first `CoinCategoryMO` in order to get them in the correct order (since your FRC is sorted using the `coinCategory` attribute).

So the direct answer is that you need to implement a `compare:` method for your `CoinCategory` class.  But I think this is just an indicator that you need to change your approach.  Rather than having an Entity with attributes that are custom objects (or collections thereof), you should probably aim to have multiple Entities (eg. a `CoinMO` entity, a `CoinCategoryMO` entity, a `CoinCategoryTypeMO` entity, etc) with to-many relationships between them.  If you show the code for your custom objects (`Coin` and `CoinCategory`) it will be easier to advise how best to model them in CoreData.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. It is greatly appreciated. How would I implement the **compare** method? This is my first time working in core data and everything that I have googled has frustrated me. Now, I am going to edit this post and post my Coin and CoinCategory classes.

Comment: My core data relationship is as following: Generated class called "CoinCategoryMO" that has a "coinCategory" entity of the type "transformable" which is of the class type CoinCategory. However, my main goal is to just resolve this problem and not gut my application's approach completely and to start anew. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @PhysNerd If you want to try implementing **compare**, you will need to add a compare method to your CoinCategory class.  It should take a single argument, of type CoinCategory, and should return a `ComparisonResult` (see the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/comparisonresult)).  But I suspect you will hit further problems even if you get past this one.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think that instead of using a CoinCategory class with a Compare method, I will add in an attribute called "index" for each CoinCategoryMO object that will represent the index of the coin category in the tableview of all the coins, use it as a sorting key, and that will fix it. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @PhysNerd Good plan.

Comment: Thanks again for the help!!